# Got LNK2019 Error in VS 2015 but not in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, lnk2019

i am having a solution with multiple projects in C++.
when I compile this solution in Visual Studio 2013 I get no errors

when I try to compile the same solution file in visual studio 2015 I got the  linker error LNK2019 [error image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT09K.png)

{`Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl adl::SJobs::addAdf(struct adl::SObjects const &,class TAc<int>)" (?addAdf@SJobs@adl@@QEAAXAEBUSObjects@2@V?$TAc@H@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl CDialogRun::getJobs(struct adl::SJobs &)" (?getJobs@CDialogRun@@AEAAXAEAUSJobs@adl@@@Z)   acad_daylight   E:\New Volume\Haseeb\Light Vidia\Lightvidia ACAD 2017\Testing in VS2015\Source Code - Copy\acad_daylight\adl_dlg_run.obj    1`

}

Comment: Please, don't include textual output as image. Instead, please, copy this output as text (and format as code e.g. using the **{}** tool button). Due to the security policy of my company, I cannot load/see images when I'm at work.

Comment: It is probably due to the difference in path settings on both the environment

Comment: will you please describe which path....?

Comment: Down at the bottom of Visual Studio you should find a tab that allows you to switch between the graphical error list and a complete text crawl of the build instructions and error messages. Often these text error messages are more useful than the abbreviated graphical version and these should be used in your questions here, assuming the extra information doesn't allow you to solve your problem without a question.

Comment: Looks like you're not linking to the proper import library or you've not added the cpp file which contains the implementations of the functions to your project.

Comment: if it so then why no error in VS2013 ?